# Does OkHttp support dynamic table in Http/2 when working as a request sender (writer)?

Tags: okhttp, http2

Dynamic table is a part of the header compression protocal (HPACK) in Http/2. Now from the source code of OkHttp, I think it supports dynamic table when working as a reader. But when working as a request sender, it doesn't, am I right?

If I'm wrong, how to let OkHttp add some headers into dynamic tables? Or does it will do it automatically?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, this is an opportunity to improve OkHttp’s HTTP/2 performance. Please open a feature request on the OkHttp issue tracker so we can remember to implement this.

Comment: I see. Add a request now: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2530